# SSLcertificate verification failed :No peer Certificate using ACRA in android application

Tags: android, crash, acra

last week i saw a library called ACRA(application crash Report for Android) for more details   [Click here](http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/ACRA3HowTo):

I was implemented the same procedure in my android application and i installed the application in my samsung mobile its sending all crash report files to my registered Gmail documents.while am using some other android mobile am getting the exception like see the logs:

```
01-01 20:55:35.193: E/ACRA(985): Failed to send crash report for 1262378355000-    approved.stacktrace
01-01 20:55:35.193: E/ACRA(985): org.acra.sender.ReportSenderException: Error while  sending report to Google Form.
01-01 20:55:35.193: E/ACRA(985):    at org.acra.sender.GoogleFormSender.send(GoogleFormSender.java:88)
01-01 20:55:35.193: E/ACRA(985):    at org.acra.SendWorker.sendCrashReport(SendWorker.java:178)
01-01 20:55:35.193: E/ACRA(985):    at org.acra.SendWorker.checkAndSendReports(SendWorker.java:141)
01-01 20:55:35.193: E/ACRA(985):    at org.acra.SendWorker.run(SendWorker.java:77)
01-01 20:55:35.193: E/ACRA(985): Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
01-01 20:55:35.193: E/ACRA(985):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:289)
01-01 20:55:35.193: E/ACRA(985):    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:124)
01-01 20:55:35.193: E/ACRA(985):    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:412)
01-01 20:55:35.193: E/ACRA(985):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:195)
01-01 20:55:35.193: E/ACRA(985):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:195)
01-01 20:55:35.193: E/ACRA(985):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:150)
01-01 20:55:35.193: E/ACRA(985):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:390)
01-01 20:55:35.193: E/ACRA(985):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:586)
01-01 20:55:35.193: E/ACRA(985):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:518)
01-01 20:55:35.193: E/ACRA(985):    at org.acra.util.HttpRequest.sendPost(HttpRequest.java:132)
01-01 20:55:35.193: E/ACRA(985):    at org.acra.sender.GoogleFormSender.send(GoogleFormSender.java:85)

it seems to be a untrusted signature/cerfication in the mobile.will u guys know about this problem
```